# XML - Adding a Node to middle of a Text Node

Tags: java, xml

How to add a node to text node in Java? I want to do this on a xml document

From:
`<doc> My Long text </doc>`

To:
`<doc> My <b>Long</b> text </doc>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this xml stored in a string?

Comment: What java xml library are you using, IIRC there are several.  I'm pretty sure when I was working with JDOM there was no way to do it other than outputting the entire document to text, making my manipulation "manually" (via old fashioned string manipulation) and then parsing it back into dom.  That was a long time ago though, so I may be thinking of something else...

Comment: @Hasan I want to do this on a xml document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've parsed the XML and have a DOM.  What you need to do is:

1. Delete the existing text node from the `<doc>` element.
2. Insert the a text node consisting of the first part of the text into the `<doc>` element.
3. Insert an element node for the `<b>` element into the `<doc>` element.
4. Insert the text content into the `<b>` element.
5. Insert the a text node consisting of the remainder of the text into the `<doc>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in such simple scenarios all you need to do, is to convert the xml into a string and perform a "string replace". This would involve much less code. But if you are restricted to working  in xml format, then follow the instructions provided by @Stephen C, using any api e.g jdom